# Vuex, webpacker and sharing state between multiple packs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, webpack, webpacker

I'm currently working on a rails project where we use webpacker. I want to be able to create small dynamic components and wrap these in packs. We want to be able to use these packs as elements within our server side rendered html. While this works (we currently have a pack for each component) I don't know what the best way would be for sharing the vuex store between these packs. I'm guessing this can be done through webpacker but i'm not sure.

the situation eg:

```
 dynamic_component_one data-id="abc"
 dynamic_component_two data-id="abc

 = javascript_pack_tag 'dynamic_component_one'
 = javascript_pack_tag 'dynamic_component_two'
```

Basically what i want to achieve is that

dynamic_component_1 and dynamic_component_2 share a common vuex store

My current solution exists of the following and feels very hacky. I register the Vue constructor and Vuex Store to the global window object to re-use them in different packs.

```
const vuex_store = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true
});

window['vue'] = Vue
window['vuex_store'] = vuex_store
```

if anyone could point me in the right direction i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to share vuex state between two javascript bundles - when both are loaded. This is always going to be a bit hacky. Your solution sounds good to me, because you do need to step outside of vue (that is: js).

Comment: Yep you understood correctly. Thanks for your input! We were thinking that maybe we could use the commonchunks plugin of webpack to handle distributing the store across multiple bundles. Not sure yet how that would work out though

Comment: hi nicky have you ever found a better way to this. I have the same need but with react packs

Comment: Hi @masciugo I just kept using the way as proposed above. Attach the store to the window object and let all the components make use of it.

Comment: Hi @NickyRomeijn. this problem has occurred to me as well. and I am kinda new to vue. So may I know how u use window['vue'] and window['vuex_store '] in packs ?