# Vuex on global window instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Ok so this is a pretty complicated question but I appreciate any help.

I have vue webpacker running on a rails application, I would like to use Vuex on it however all Vue components are unrelated, a solution I found online ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869454/vuex-webpacker-and-sharing-state-between-multiple-packs)) was someone who added Vuex to the global window instance and imported that javascript into his main layout, I have done so and can see properly that a Vuex instance exists on my global window instance.

The code for that javascript I'm running is this:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);
const vuex_store = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
});

window["vue"] = Vue;
window["vuex_store"] = vuex_store;
```

Now my question is, in an unrelated vue component also running on my rails server, how would I import and use this Vuex instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used it as a bus directly as I wanted initially.

`window.vue.$on` and `window.vue.$emit` anywhere